# iis cant find a javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, master-pages

I have a problem with my a javascript file im refrencing to a master page.

this is the code:

```
<head runat="server">
   <type="text/javascript" src="../Jquery1.6_vsdoc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
```

the jquery files work fine, but the main.js not.
when i open the aspex file on the web browser and do view source, and try to see the code on the main.js file iis show this message:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

what do i do worng here?

some info on the file (if it will help):

1. he is the same directory of the master page
2. he is ony refreced in 1 master page.

im using visual studio 2012
(sorry for my english)

Comment: My understanding of "master pages" is that they are a template, so the directory they are stored is unrelated to the URI of the document being viewed (so having the JS file in the same directory as one doesn't tell us anything about if that is the right place or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Page.ResolveUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) in Master Page scenarios

so your reference should look like this

```
   <type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Jquery1.6_vsdoc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/main.js") %>"></script>
```

This will ensure that the page is mapped correctly as the Child Page may not be in the same location as the Master Page

Comment: im confused. the problem is with the main.js file, but i need to do the Page.ResolveUrl to the jquery 1?

Comment: Hey @samy I didn't do both links as I was typing in a rush (fixing a server problem atm), but the problem is caused by where you're main.js file is in relation to the page you're loading. Page.ResolveUrl deals with this discrepancy and is what I generally use when calling resources in the Master Page. So, I would recommend doing it for all such links.

Comment: i think im not using this right, becuse when i do view source i cant see nothing in the src attribute of the script elememt. they are both empty :(

Comment: @samy see the edit. I omitted the = after the % which is required to wrap a call to Response.Write().

Comment: now i can see the files, and can accses the jquery 1, but the main.js still return 404 (the same error i post in the question) :(

Comment: @samy Since your main.js is not on "root", you have to put the right path in the ResolveUrl call, which would be wherever your master page file is located. Or you can place main.js in root/scripts (new folder) and then do ResolveUrl("~/scripts/main.js"). I am assuming your MasterPage is not on root of your application.

Comment: Thanks! like you said, I had to put the name of the folder even if the file it self is inside this of it. i have a fast quesiton: should i use the Page.ResolveUrl() in Master pages only or in every file on my website for example aspex files?